# Can a mouse emulate swiping?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, mouse

I use Moon+ Reader software to read pdf files on a Sony xperia tablet. Instead of swiping on the screen to scroll the pdf, I would like to use a mouse with scrolling wheel instead to scroll. Is this possible and what do I need?
Using 4.2.2.

Comment: Most likely you'd need a mouse with a scrolling wheel :) Honestly: Have you tried whether it works? What happens if you scroll? As long the answer is not "nothing", you could check with Moony's config and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I have to get a mini USB to USB to test. I don't expect it's in config because what I am asking is unusual. No there's no mouse setting in Moon+. I am asking if there's a software driver/tool which translates mouse wheel movements into swiping commands which Android understands and which any Android software responds to.

Comment: How do you know there's no "mouse setting" in Moon+? Sure it's not labeled such, as it's rather unusual (as you already noted). My hope for you is the scrolling event submitted by the mouse *might* match one of the other events which can be configured. Small chance, but at least it is.

Comment: If it's a setting that deals with the mouse, why would it be labeled something that doesn't mention mouse!? You're talking about low level programming. People usually don't use a mouse with Android and among the tens of Android apps I used, none mentioned mouse in any of their settings.

Comment: It wouldn't be labeled such because it was not intended for this. Let me explain by an (incorrect) example: couldn't it be the scroll-up event triggers the same "interrupt" as the volume-up key (unlikely, but I wrote it's incorrect)? In that case, wouldn't Moon+ react as if you had pushed the volume-up key? And if so, couldn't you use that for your purpose, substituting "scroll-up" with what's named "volume up" in Moon+?

Comment: There's no scroll or mouse setting.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601085) shows that you can capture touch input from the raw device (`/dev/input/event2') to a file, and then play it back whenever you like. You could then automate an event to play back the captured touch input each time you want to scroll.

Comment: Are you suggesting I program this? I am not an Android programmer. I am looking for a tool.

Answer (score 0):

If your Xperia tablet is rooted... use an app called Tasker. It is able to emulate to send touch and swipe events to the screen. I have used it in several apps to scroll the screen up. Of course you can use Tasker if the device *isn't* rooted, but I'm not sure if you can send shell commands.

In Tasker, create a new task, Action category CODE--> RUN SHELL--> input swipe X1 Y1 X2 Y2

Check out this link: http://www.pocketables.com/2013/07/how-to-emulate-touch-input-using-tasker-and-root.html

You can also use Tasker to send button events to emulate a directional pad. Just send x amount of clicks in order to scroll the appropriate amount of the screen.

Now you just have to figure out how you want to trigger that task to run.

If this works, let me know!

Comment: And how to bind that to the mouse? AFAIK there's no way to tell Tasker the mouse input directly, but I might have missed that.